# ASP.NET EntityFraord - Grid com Paginação

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

estou construindo uma aplicação asp.net utilizando entity framwork. Para carregar o grid eu utilizo as seguintes instruções:

```
        var lista = entity.Usuario.ToList().OrderBy(x=>x.nome);
        grid.DataSource = lista;
        grid.DataBind();
```

Porém quando eu tento configurar paginação no grid é exibido o seguinte erro:

> [NotSupportedException: A fonte de dados não oferece suporte para
>   paginação de dados no servidor.]
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.RaiseUnsupportedCapabilityError(DataSourceCapabilities
>   capability) +2875489
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceSelectArguments.RaiseUnsupportedCapabilitiesError(DataSourceView
>   view) +62
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ReadOnlyDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments) +17
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +22
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable
>   dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +367
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data) +67
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data) +14
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable
>   data) +128
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +34
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +9
>   Refeitorio.paginas.CadUsuariosaspx.carregarGrid() in
>   C:\Users\sv111727\Source\Refeitorio\Refeitorio\Refeitorio\Refeitorio\paginas\CadUsuariosaspx.aspx.cs:55
>   Refeitorio.paginas.CadUsuariosaspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) in
>   C:\Users\sv111727\Source\Refeitorio\Refeitorio\Refeitorio\Refeitorio\paginas\CadUsuariosaspx.aspx.cs:16
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +51    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +780

Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema?

Comment: testou a sugestão apresentada em minha resposta?

Comment: Um erro "bobo", o autor nunca mais voltou para ver a resposta e não acredito que possa ser muito útil para outros usuários.

Answer (score 1):

O problema está na sequência como você está executando, ao declarar a `var lista` finalizando com um `OrderBy()` você está retornando um `IOrderdEnumerable<>`, que não implementa a `ICollection` necessária para o suporte à paginação no `GridView`. Passe o `ToList()` para o final da sua declaração, assim o seu DataSource recebera um `IEnumerable<>`.

```
var lista = entity.Usuario.OrderBy(x=>x.nome).ToList();
grid.DataSource = lista;
grid.DataBind();
```

Fonte:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/5aw1xfh3(v=vs.100).aspx